# Label switching value on condition

Tags: tikz-pgf, conditionals, labels

I try to create a dynamic graph where a node move along the axis line.
When a condition on x is filled (X>1.8), I need the labels to be translated as i tried to do it in the following MWE

```
  \documentclass{beamer}
  \usepackage{tikz}
  \usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning} 

\begin{document}
%definition des styles des noeuds
\tikzstyle{D0}=
[draw=yellow!40,fill=red!40,circle,minimum size=20]
\tikzstyle{N_date}=[circle, draw=yellow!40, fill=yellow!80,minimum size=20]
\tikzstyle{comment}=[rectangle, rounded corners,minimum size=20]
\tikzstyle{fleche}=[->, dashed,thick]

\def\Cotango{1}
\def\FactorOne{1}


\foreach \i in {0.1,0.2,...,2.2}
{\begin{frame}
    {Futures dynamic}
    \begin{center}
        \resizebox{7cm}{!}
    {
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            %x axis
            \draw[->, thick] (0,0) -- (10,0);
            %S_0 is moving along the axis
            \node [D0]  (Start) at (\i,0) {$S_0$};

            \ifdim\i pt<1.8pt\relax
                \node [comment] (E1) at (2,5) {\small{1$^{st}$ maturity}};
                \node [comment] (E2) at (5,5) {\small{2$^{nd}$ maturity}};
                \node [comment] (E3) at (8,5) {\small{3$^{rd}$ maturity}};

                    %4- Noeuds des Forwards cotango
                    \ifnum\numexpr\Cotango>0\relax
                        \node [N_date] (FC1) at (2,{ln(2*\FactorOne)}) {\small{$F_1$}};
                        \node [N_date] (FC2) at (5,{ln(5*\FactorOne)}) {\small{$F_2$}};
                        \node [N_date] (FC3) at (8,{ln(8*\FactorOne)}){\small{$F_3$}};
                        \draw [fleche] (FC1) to [bend left=45] (FC2);
                    \draw [fleche] (FC2) to [bend left=45] (FC3);
                    \draw [fleche] (Start) to [bend left=45] (FC1);
                \fi
            \fi

            \ifdim\i pt>=1.8pt\relax
%                   \node [comment] (E1) at (2,5) {\small{1$^{st}$ maturity}};
                    \node [comment] (E2) at (5,5) {\small{1$^{st}$ maturity}};
                    \node [comment] (E3) at (8,5) {\small{2$^{nd}$ maturity}};

                %4- Noeuds des Forwards cotango
                \ifnum\numexpr\Cotango>0\relax
%                       \node [N_date] (FC1) at (2,{ln(2*\FactorOne)}) {\small{$F_1$}};
                        \node [N_date] (FC2) at (5,{ln(5*\FactorOne)}) {\small{$F_1$}};
                        \node [N_date] (FC3) at (8,{ln(8*\FactorOne)}){\small{$F_2$}};
%                       \draw [fleche] (FC1) to [bend left=45] (FC2);
                        \draw [fleche] (FC2) to [bend left=45] (FC3);
                        \draw [fleche] (Start) to [bend left=45] (FC2);
                    \fi
            \fi

        \end{tikzpicture}
    }
\end{center}
\end{frame}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

When S_0 gets close to F_1, F_1 disappears, F_2 becomes F_1, F_3 become F_2. Getting back to the initial graph.

[image]

[image]

Based on @marmot solution, here is an updated code where I still miss the F_2 becomes F_1, F_3 become F_2.

```
  \documentclass{beamer}
   \usepackage{tikz}
   \usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning} 
    \usetikzlibrary{calc,decorations,decorations.pathreplacing}

  \begin{document}
  %definition des styles des noeuds
  \def\Cotango{1}
  \def\modifRand{abs(rand*0.4)}
  \def\FactorOne{1}

  \pgfmathsetseed{1}
  \tikzset{
     D0/.style={draw=red,fill=red!40,circle,minimum size=20},
    N_date/.style={circle, draw=yellow!40, fill=yellow!80,minimum size=20},
    comment/.style={rectangle, fill=blue!40,rounded corners,minimum size=20},
    fleche/.style={->,thin},
    jump/.style={insert path={ edge[bend left=45,fleche] 
        (-1+#1*3,{ln((-1+#1*3)*\FactorOne)+\modifRand})
        (-1+#1*3,{ln((-1+#1*3)*\FactorOne)+\modifRand}) node[N_date] (F-#1)
        {\small{$F_{{#1}}$}} (F-#1) }}}


\foreach \i in {0.3,0.6,...,8.0}
{\begin{frame}
   {Futures dynamic}
    \begin{center}
    \resizebox{7cm}{!}
    {
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            %x axis
            \draw[gray!80,->, thick] (0,0) -- (10,0);
            %S_0 is moving along the axis

    \ifdim\i pt<1.8pt\relax                   
            \draw[fleche] node [D0]  (Start) at (\i,0) {$S_0$} [jump/.list={1,2,3}];
            \node [comment] (E1) at (2,5) {\small{1$^{st}$ maturity}};
            \node [comment] (E2) at (5,5) {\small{2$^{nd}$ maturity}};
            \node [comment] (E3) at (8,5) {\small{3$^{rd}$ maturity}};
    \else
        \ifdim\i pt<4.8pt\relax 
            \draw[fleche] node [D0]  (Start) at (\i,0) {$S_0$} [jump/.list={2,3}];
            \node [comment] (E2) at (5,5) {\small{1$^{st}$ maturity}};
            \node [comment] (E3) at (8,5) {\small{2$^{nd}$ maturity}};
        \else
            \draw[fleche] node [D0]  (Start) at (\i,0) {$S_0$} [jump=3];
            \node [comment] (E3) at (8,5) {\small{1$^{st}$ maturity}};

        \fi 
    \fi

        \end{tikzpicture}
    }
    \end{center}
    \end{frame}
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can only use integers with `\ifnum`. On the other hand, `\ifdim` works with noninteger dimensions. So if you replace `\ifnum\i<1.8\relax` by `\ifdim\i pt<1.8pt\relax` your code runs through. Whether or not this is the desired outcome I don't know.

Comment: @marmot. Thank you. I updated my code with your comment and updated it so that I can better show the switch effect in labels when \i>=1.8. This code is not elegant at all. Would you see a solution where labels would be in a list ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, I am very busy now, so this is a quick proposal. Yes, you can repeat things, this is what the `/.list` key does. And, as already mentioned, it is a standard trick to convert a number to a dimension to be able to play with non-integers.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
%definition des styles des noeuds
\def\Cotango{1}
\def\modifRand{abs(rand*0.4)}
\def\FactorOne{1}

\pgfmathsetseed{1}
\tikzset{
   D0/.style={draw=red,fill=red!40,circle,minimum size=20},
  N_date/.style={circle, draw=yellow!40, fill=yellow!80,minimum size=20},
  comment/.style={rectangle, fill=blue!40,rounded corners,minimum size=20},
  fleche/.style={->,thin},
  jump/.style args={#1|#2}{insert path={ edge[bend left=45,fleche] 
      (-1+#1*3,{ln((-1+#1*3)*\FactorOne)+\modifRand})
      (-1+#1*3,{ln((-1+#1*3)*\FactorOne)+\modifRand}) node[N_date,font=\small] (F-#1)
      {$F_{{#2}}$} (F-#1) }}}


\foreach \i in {0.3,0.6,...,8.0}
{\begin{frame}
   {Futures dynamic}
    \begin{center}
    \resizebox{7cm}{!}
    {
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            %x axis
            \draw[gray!80,->, thick] (0,0) -- (10,0);
            %S_0 is moving along the axis

    \ifdim\i pt<1.8pt\relax                   
            \draw[fleche] node [D0]  (Start) at (\i,0) {$S_0$} 
            [jump/.list={1|1,2|2,3|3}];
            \node [comment] (E1) at (2,5) {\small{1$^{st}$ maturity}};
            \node [comment] (E2) at (5,5) {\small{2$^{nd}$ maturity}};
            \node [comment] (E3) at (8,5) {\small{3$^{rd}$ maturity}};
    \else
        \ifdim\i pt<4.8pt\relax 
            \draw[fleche] node [D0]  (Start) at (\i,0) {$S_0$} 
            [jump/.list={2|1,3|2}];
            \node [comment] (E2) at (5,5) {\small{1$^{st}$ maturity}};
            \node [comment] (E3) at (8,5) {\small{2$^{nd}$ maturity}};
        \else
            \draw[fleche] node [D0]  (Start) at (\i,0) {$S_0$} [jump=3|1];
            \node [comment] (E3) at (8,5) {\small{1$^{st}$ maturity}};

        \fi 
    \fi

        \end{tikzpicture}
    }
    \end{center}
    \end{frame}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You're a magician !

Comment: @Julien-ElieTaieb No, just a marmot. (You may already know [these](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wrIcTyafjyY) ;-)

Comment: ahahah. :) I updated my code based on youre great solution but with a little adjusmnet you'll see. To be the final solution, I need F2 to become F1 and F3 to become S2 when the threshold is reached.
thank you marmot !

Comment: @Julien-ElieTaieb I made an update. Does that go in the right direction? (If so, I will try to get rid of the strange behavior of the arcs.)

Comment: This is it!! Merci marmot :)

Comment: @Julien-ElieTaieb You're welcome! You can remove the jumps by replacing `\def\modifRand{abs(rand*0.4)}` by `\pgfmathsetmacro{\modifRand}{abs(rand*0.4)}`, but it seems to me that you might have done this precisely because you wanted these jumps, so I didn't touch that.

Comment: It's great to have the option of the jumps (and the solution to it!)